# Send information to the Clipboard - old method fails - new method

Tags: vba, clipboard

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/Concepts/Windows-API/send-information-to-the-clipboard

Reformatted code to ptrsafe but getting an error : The StrPtr() Is actually LongLong- but changing it in either place doesn't push the data to the clipboard...

Issue in OUTLOOK and EXCEL with push functions.

Suggestions?

```
Attribute VB_Name = "MyClipboardAPI"
''https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/Concepts/Windows-API/send-information-to-the-clipboard
Option Explicit
Private Declare PtrSafe Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function EmptyClipboard Lib "user32.dll" () As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32.dll" () As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function IsClipboardFormatAvailable Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetClipboardData Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetClipboardData Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal wFormat As Long, ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalAlloc Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal wFlags As Long, ByVal dwBytes As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalLock Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalUnlock Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalSize Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function lstrcpy Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "lstrcpyW" (ByVal lpString1 As Long, ByVal lpString2 As Long) As Long

Public Sub PushToClipboardAPI(sUniText As String)
    Dim iStrPtr As Long
    Dim iLen As Long
    Dim iLock As Long
    Const GMEM_MOVEABLE As Long = &H2
    Const GMEM_ZEROINIT As Long = &H40
    Const CF_UNICODETEXT As Long = &HD
    OpenClipboard 0&
    EmptyClipboard
    iLen = LenB(sUniText) + 2&
    iStrPtr = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE Or GMEM_ZEROINIT, iLen)
    iLock = GlobalLock(iStrPtr)
    lstrcpy iLock, StrPtr(sUniText)
    GlobalUnlock iStrPtr
    SetClipboardData CF_UNICODETEXT, iStrPtr
    CloseClipboard
End Sub

Public Function GetClipboard() As String
    Dim iStrPtr As Long
    Dim iLen As Long
    Dim iLock As Long
    Dim sUniText As String
    Const CF_UNICODETEXT As Long = 13&
OpenClipboard 0&
If IsClipboardFormatAvailable(CF_UNICODETEXT) Then
    iStrPtr = GetClipboardData(CF_UNICODETEXT)
    If iStrPtr Then
        iLock = GlobalLock(iStrPtr)
        iLen = GlobalSize(iStrPtr)
        sUniText = String$(iLen \ 2& - 1&, vbNullChar)
        lstrcpy StrPtr(sUniText), iLock
        GlobalUnlock iStrPtr
    End If
    GetClipboard = sUniText
End If
CloseClipboard
```

End Function

Answer (score 2):

from:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/48e8c30c-24ee-458e-a873-a4e6e13f5926/dataobject-settext-and-putinclipboard-sequence-puts-invalid-data-hex-63-characters-in-clipboard?forum=isvvba

Modified - 4 lines of code to longptr types:

```
''https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/Concepts/Windows-API/send-information-to-the-clipboard
Option Explicit

    Private Declare PtrSafe Function OpenClipboard Lib "User32" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function EmptyClipboard Lib "User32" () As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function CloseClipboard Lib "User32" () As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function IsClipboardFormatAvailable Lib "User32" (ByVal wFormat As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetClipboardData Lib "User32" (ByVal wFormat As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetClipboardData Lib "User32" (ByVal wFormat As LongPtr, ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalAlloc Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal wFlags As Long, ByVal dwBytes As Long) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalLock Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalUnlock Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalSize Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function lstrcpy Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "lstrcpyW" (ByVal lpString1 As Any, ByVal lpString2 As Any) As LongPtr


Public Sub PushToClipboardAPI(sUniText As String)
    Dim iStrPtr As LongPtr
    Dim iLock As LongPtr
    Dim iLen As Long
    Const GMEM_MOVEABLE As Long = &H2
    Const GMEM_ZEROINIT As Long = &H40
    Const CF_UNICODETEXT As Long = &HD
    OpenClipboard 0&
    EmptyClipboard
    iLen = LenB(sUniText) + 2&
    iStrPtr = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE Or GMEM_ZEROINIT, iLen)
    iLock = GlobalLock(iStrPtr)
    Dim spv As LongLong

    spv = StrPtr(sUniText)
    lstrcpy iLock, spv
    GlobalUnlock iStrPtr
    SetClipboardData CF_UNICODETEXT, iStrPtr
    CloseClipboard
End Sub

Public Function GetClipboard() As String
    Dim iStrPtr As LongPtr
    Dim iLock As LongPtr
    Dim iLen As Long
    Dim sUniText As String
    Const CF_UNICODETEXT As Long = 13&
    OpenClipboard 0&
    If IsClipboardFormatAvailable(CF_UNICODETEXT) Then
        iStrPtr = GetClipboardData(CF_UNICODETEXT)
        If iStrPtr Then
            iLock = GlobalLock(iStrPtr)
            iLen = GlobalSize(iStrPtr)
            sUniText = String$(iLen \ 2& - 1&, vbNullChar)
            lstrcpy StrPtr(sUniText), iLock
            GlobalUnlock iStrPtr
        End If
        GetClipboard = sUniText
    End If
    CloseClipboard
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

I just came across this while researching Windows clipboard APIs in reference to Excel/VBA. Note that the function definitions in the post from Apsis0215 above, are still wrong! They might technically work on Win64, but they are not correct.

First, `OpenClipboard()`, `EmptyClipboard()`, `CloseClipboard()`, `IsClipboardFormatAvailable()`, `GlobalUnlock()` all return a *BOOL* datatype (which is ultimately defined as a 'signed int', which is 32-bit. They are not pointers! As such they should not be defined with `As LongPtr`, but rather with **`As Long`**, even in Vba7 and/or Win64. (Not `As Boolean` either by the way, since the Boolean datatype in VBA is only 16-bit).

Second, all of the `wFormat` parameters in all of the functions expect an *UINT* datatype (32-bit 'unsigned int'). And as such should be defined with **`As Long`**, even on Vba7 and/or Win64!

Third, the `dwBytes` parameter of function `GlobalAlloc()` has datatype *SIZE_T*, which means that must be declared with `As LongPtr`, not `As Long`. The same for the return datatype of the function `GlobalSize()`, that too is of datatype *SIZE_T* and thus should also be `As LongPtr`.

Please see official Windows API references and VBA references.

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function OpenClipboard Lib "USER32.DLL" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function EmptyClipboard Lib "USER32.DLL" () As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CloseClipboard Lib "USER32.DLL" () As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function IsClipboardFormatAvailable Lib "USER32.DLL" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetClipboardData Lib "USER32.DLL" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetClipboardData Lib "USER32.DLL" (ByVal wFormat As Long, ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalAlloc Lib "KERNEL32.DLL" (ByVal uFlags As Long, ByVal dwBytes As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalLock Lib "KERNEL32.DLL" (ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalUnlock Lib "KERNEL32.DLL" (ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalSize Lib "KERNEL32.DLL" (ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function lstrcpy Lib "KERNEL32.DLL" Alias "lstrcpyW" (ByVal lpString1 As Any, ByVal lpString2 As Any) As LongPtr
```

Comment: Eric- These are 'quick-fixes' from old 32 bit to the new 64 bit. Appreciate the filling in on the correct types. If they are coming from 32 bit is there still a risk of overflow when pushing into 64bit? Is it worth the allocation of more space and what risk of overruns are there?